# How to add multiple annotations in map view

Tags: ios, swift3, annotations, mapkit

I have to show 5 points(Which is in Array) in my map view. I have shown the Array value in my log.Loop was running perfectly and annotations are not getting added.This is my code:

```
            self.mapView.delegate = self
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
            self.mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
            self.mapView.isScrollEnabled = true
            self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        print("LOCATION LIST==>>")
        print(items["Location"].arrayValue)

        for locationList in items["Location"].arrayValue
        {
            print(locationList)

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationList["latitude"].doubleValue, longitude: locationList["longitude"].doubleValue)
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)    
        }

        self.mapView.delegate = self
```

Log:

```
LOCATION LIST==>>
{
  "Latitude" : 12.988415,
  "Longtitude" : 80.218386
}, {
  "Latitude" : 12.988445,
  "Longtitude" : 80.21839199999999
}, {
  "Latitude" : 12.988492,
  "Longtitude" : 80.218422
}, {
  "Latitude" : 12.988558,
  "Longtitude" : 80.218461
},  
{
  "Latitude" : 12.991181,
  "Longtitude" : 80.21950200000001
}
```

But it is not showing Annotations in my map View.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by manipulating `MKMapView's delegate`

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    print("viewForAnnotation \(annotation.title)")
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }
    let reuseID = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseID) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if(pinView == nil) {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseID)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.animatesDrop = true
    }
    return pinView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the region is not selected properly. So to focus all the annotations either use the following api ->

```
func showAnnotations(_ annotations: [MKAnnotation], 
        animated: Bool)
```

Use

```
    self.mapView.showAnnotations(annotations, animated: true)
```

Or try setting a region based on your annotations which fits all your annotation -> focus markers

```
 func getVisibleRectForAnnotation(markers : [MKPointAnnotation?],width:Double) -> MKMapRect{
    var zoomRect:MKMapRect = MKMapRectNull

    for index in 0..<markers.count {
        let annotation = markers[index]
        if let annotation = annotation{
            let aPoint:MKMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)
            let rect:MKMapRect = MKMapRectMake(aPoint.x, aPoint.y, width, width)
            if MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect) {
                zoomRect = rect
            } else {
                zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, rect)
            }
        }
    }
    return zoomRect
}

func focusMarkers(markers : [MKPointAnnotation?],width:Double){

    let zoomRect = getVisibleRectForAnnotation(markers: markers, width: width)

    if(!MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect)){
        let mapEdgePadding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 40, left: 40, bottom: 40, right: 40)
        mapView.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, edgePadding: mapEdgePadding, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Comment: Question is in swift code, so you should take a look first and then answer without Objective-C code.